# How to prevent Google from indexing a site?

Tags: html, google-index

My client asked me to prevent google bot from indexing the website, so I have added the following meta to the head tag of my main layer which (in theory) is the head of all pages:

```
<meta name="googlebot" content="noindex">
```

This should prevent Google from indexing any pages, however, it is not preventing it. Apparently my client observed somehow that Google bots are still indexing the site (I do not know how he knows that Google is still indexing the site, because, as usual, clients are not too descriptive) so it seems that this is not solving the problem.

In fact I wanted to prevent google from indexing the site by adding a meta in the header of my template used at all the pages. Why is this still not enough for google to prevent it from indexing the site? How should I fix the issue?

Thank you very much.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Comment: We cannot know why your client believes that Google bots are indexing the site. We cannot even ask him about it.

Comment: True, but this is a typical problem: we want to be able to detect this type of problem and solve it. Detecting the problem is part of the solution.

Answer (score 4):

TL;DR: Google might accidentally ignore the meta tag that you added to the website. If you recently added the meta tag it will follow it when the bot recrawls the website. If you want to get rid of all search bots, and not just google use 
 `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`

Here is the official answer from Google -

> "Note that because we have to crawl your page in order to see the
>   noindex meta tag, there's a small chance that Googlebot won't see and
>   respect the noindex meta tag. If your page is still appearing in
>   results, it's probably because we haven't crawled your site since you
>   added the tag. (Also, if you've used your robots.txt file to block
>   this page, we won't be able to see the tag either.)
>
> If the content is currently in our index, we will remove it after the
>   next time we crawl it. To expedite removal, use the URL removal
>   request tool in Google Webmaster Tools."

Also, please note that your client may be confusing the Google bot with another webcrawler bot. In that case, I recommend adding:

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

To the HTML document
so that no webcrawlers can index the site, not just googlebot.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, no we are talking about Google specifically, so I am happy if Yahoo crawls the pages, but google doesn't. I have also read the quoted text from your answer when I was researching the matter, I was aware of it, but I have added it approx. a month ago and I wonder whether the meta described in my answer is wrong somehow, because it either behaves differently then it should, or my client misunderstood something. Anyway, I have asked the question because I believe it is better to make things clearer, because I believe people will have the same question in the future.

Answer (score 1):

I've always done `<meta name="robots" content="noindex">`.

You can see https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/93710?hl=en and https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/156449?hl=en&ref_topic=2370588 for a little more info.

The reason your tags might not work is if you have a robots.txt file blocking Google from re-indexing the site.

Comment: I am not preventing google from accessing the site using robots.txt. I have tried to prevent google from indexing the site by adding the meta tag described in my question. And I believe it should work, but my client believes Google is still indexing the site. Why I believe it should work: https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/79812?hl=en

Comment: @LajosArpad Did you Google the site in question yourself and find results? If not, maybe you should just tell the client he's nuts, after clearing his cache to make sure he gets fresh results. Then the next step to be would to be looking over your client's shoulder while he performs the search. :)